# Comparing stability of CF3+ and CD3+

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, carbocation

This is a question from my text book.

> Compare the stability of carbocation between $\ce{CF3^+}$ and $\ce{CD3+}$.

The answer is given $\ce{CF3+}$ due to backbonding.

But I see backbonding as a sort of resonance effect. And we know that for fluorine atom its inductive effect dominants its resonance effect, and so overall it is electron withdrawing. So, shouldn't the answer be $\ce{CF3+}$?

Comment: Do you know [Bent's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bent's_rule)? That should simplify comparisons here: in the CF3 cation, most of the p-character will shift towards the fluorines, and hence the central carbon bearing the positive charge will be left with a lot of s character as compared to the carbon of the CD3 cation. For the same quantum number, s orbitals are usually lower in energy than p orbitals(and that is anyway true for 2s and 2p) so the CF3 cation will probably be experiencing a greater lowering of energy, and hence be more "stable"

Comment: Do not use HW tag, it specifically says so. Also, MathJax in the title reduces searchability. Use `$\ce{}$` for chemical compounds.

Comment: *for fluorine atom its inductive effect dominants its resonance effect* - no it doesn't. Do you know how bonding in $\ce{BF3}$ works? Same thing here.